# C# change variable in different winform-classes

Tags: c#

I got a winform-class and would like to call another class ("FileInformationsWindow"). I would like to pass some variables through the classes. Somehow, I can't change the values of the "FileInformationsWindow".

```
namespace dms2
{
    public partial class main_frame : Form
{

new FileInformationsWindow() { current_level = -1, current_parent = -1}.ShowDialog();

}
}
```

```
namespace dms2
{
    public partial class FileInformationsWindow : Form
{

        public int current_level { get; set; }
        public int current_parent { get; set; }

 public FileInformationsWindow()
{
.
.
.
}
}
}
```

current_level & current_parent always remain 0.

Comment: How you check that properties remain 0?

Comment: I have set a breakpoint after the FileInformationsWindow() method is called and checked the values.

Comment: The line of code in your sample includes `.ShowDialog()` call, which means that few form events will be raised after that call. Do you have some event handlers in the `FileInformationWindow` form? For example `Form_Load` or `Form_Shown`

Comment: I am calling the new FileInformationsWindow() in an event from the main_frame (after a DragDrop-Event the method is getting called). In the FileInformationsWindow I am not calling any events. I set the breakpoint directly at the beginning of the FileInformationsWindow().

Comment: _I set the breakpoint directly at the beginning of the FileInformationsWindow()_ - can you show actual code, because current line of code should work just fine

Comment: DragDropEvent () { new FileInformationsWindow() { current_level = -1, current_parent = -1}.ShowDialog(); };

public FileInformationsWindow()
        { => breakpoint
            InitializeComponent();
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202888/discussion-between-trekki-and-fabio).

Comment: That "FileInformationsWindow() method" is the constructor. The properties are set *after* the constructor runs (because of the `{ ... }` syntax)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing is right. At the constructor invocation time the properties are still not set, you have two options. Pass the two values in the constructor or whatever code uses those properties should be moved in the Form_Load event handler

Comment: Ah thank you guys! Works now with the Form_Load event!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested this, but I think both of these should work:

```
namespace dms2
{
  public partial class main_frame : Form
  {
    private void myMethod()
    {
        FileInformationsWindow fi = new FileInformationsWindow() { current_level = -1, current_parent = -1 };
        fi.ShowDialog();

        FileInformationsWindow2 fi2 = new FileInformationsWindow2(-1, -1);
        fi2.ShowDialog();
    }
 }

 public partial class FileInformationsWindow : Form
 {

    public int current_level { get; set; }
    public int current_parent { get; set; }

    public FileInformationsWindow()
    {
    }
 }

 public partial class FileInformationsWindow2 : Form
 {

    public int current_level { get; private set; }
    public int current_parent { get; private set; }

    public FileInformationsWindow2(int currentlevel, int currentparent)
    {
        current_level = currentlevel;
        current_parent = currentparent;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I am using parameters for the FileInformationsWindow method, it's working just fine. Directly passing the variables is not working though (sample 1 of your code).

Comment: Have you tried it by splitting you code into the two lines like in this example?  Have you set breakpoints in the Set of each of the properties to check the values?

Comment: The first example will show the exact behavior like the OP original code. The problem arises because in the constructor code of FileInformationsWindow the two properties are still not set. In the Form_Load event everything should be fine

Comment: I initialise properties in a form in this way. Unless the OP is trying to access the properties in the constructor of the new form, of course - which looking back at the comments on the original question that have been added since, could well be the case.